# Testing for an infinite loop +java

Tags: java

I want to know (for exam questions) if num-- is commented out, will it cause an infinite loop. So I will try this and will get an infinite loop, which means I have to close down Eclipse and start up again. There must be a simpler way to test for an infinite loop.

```
package doWhile_loop;

public class DoWhileLoop {
    static int num = 20;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        do {
            System.out.print("\t"+num /*num--*/);}//num-- commented out to test                           
        while(num >10);
    }

}
```

Comment: thr are infinite way to create the loop.

Comment: I'm not familiar with eclipse.. but most IDEs run the program on a separate thread so there should be a stop button to kill a running program.

and no there is no simple way to test for an infinite loop http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HaltingProblem.html

Comment: In eclipse, there's a "cross" button near the output console to close your program, no need to close the whole thing.

Comment: In eclipse there's a red square to halt the running program, another idea is to use a debugger.

Comment: what's is problem statement?

Comment: You could wait for infinity++ and then it should stop by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to close eclipse. If you look in the top right corner of your console box when there is a running program, you can halt and shut down the process by clicking the little red stop button. That should end even an infinite loop. See the image below:

[image: Screenshot depicting eclipse console with red button described above.]

As long as you have a running process created by eclipse, that button will be enabled, and you can click it at any time.

Comment: @Joe Happy I could help. On SO when an answer solves your problem, you can "accept" it as the person who made the question. This makes it easier for people who come here with the same problem to find the answer quickly.

Answer (score 0):

In your `eclipse` there is a Red Button. You can press that for terminating the program.

Comment: @Joe here you have a better way to say thanks by accepting the answer ;)